# Multiple checkboxes in Android get final value

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox

I have a form that has multiple checkboxes. Each checkbox is worth a different amount 1-5,] See values in brackets in screenshot. I need to get the result of all the clicked checkboxes and add them up. Ive seem multiple ways of doing this but what is the best. If statements and switch statements seem too long. Ive seen array lists but i have three sections on the form so could I do three seperate array lists for each one and then add the values in the array?

XML

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/redflag_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="6dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- Media -->

            <!-- Buttons -->
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="184dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:contentDescription="orange_flag"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/secondary_symptoms" />


            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/gcs_test"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="320dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">

                    <!-- Title, secondary and supporting text -->
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/gcs_title"
                        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline6" />


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="@string/gcs_intro"
                        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody2"
                        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />


                    <CheckedTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:text="@string/eye_heading"
                        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody2"
                        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/cb_eye_response1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/eye_check1" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/cb_eye_response2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/eye_check2" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/cb_eye_response3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/eye_check3" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/cb_eye_response4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/eye_check4" />

                    <CheckedTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:text="@string/verbal_heading"
                        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody2"
                        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/cb_verbal_response"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/verbal_check_1" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/cb_verbal_response2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/verbal_check_2" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/cb_verbal_response3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/verbal_check_3" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/cb_verbal_response4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/verbal_check4" />

                    <CheckedTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:text="@string/motor_heading"
                        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody2"
                        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/cb_motor_response1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/motor_check_1" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/cb_motor_response2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/motor_check_2" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/cb_motor_response3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/motor_check_3" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/cb_motor_response4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:text="@string/motor_check4" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/cb_motor_response5"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/motor_check5" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/cb_motor_response6"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/motor_check6" />
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/gc_score_btn"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:onClick="updateScore"
                            android:text="@string/gcs_score" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/gcs_score_editText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        android:autofillHints=""
                        android:layout_marginStart="12dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/gcs_warning"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:background="#F10E3C"
                        android:text="@string/gcs_result_text"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />


                </LinearLayout>

            </ScrollView>


            <!--App designed Buttons to continue/call ambulance -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                    android:id="@+id/gcs_call_ambulance"
                    style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:onClick="onButtonClicked"
                    android:text="@string/call_ambulance" />

                <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                    android:id="@+id/gcs_continue"
                    style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="onButtonClicked"
                    android:text="@string/continue_diagnosis" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image: App design]

Comment: You should use RecyclerView with multiple view types. you can google it. But for more detail, you should create a Class with two variables: 1- Question 2- Answers. that answer is a list of answers. and pass a list of your class to the RecyclerView to show it

Comment: But I need the headings best eye response, best verbal response included also will a recycler not just implement all the questions?

Comment: I think this the best solution if you are not familiar with RecyclerViewe and ViewTypes please google it.